# Find a set of generators for operations with ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

The problem in question is to find a set of generators for the following operation of ideals:

$i)$ $(f) \cap (g)$, where $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime elements of a factorial domain;

$ii)$ $(X,Y) \cap (X,Z) \cap (Y,Z)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]$;

$iii)$ $(X,Y) \cap (X,Z) \cap (X,W) \cap (Y,Z) \cap (Y,W) \cap (Z,W)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z, W]$

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: No. I would like to understand these operations better, I have a hard time understanding how they work.So far I have not been able to see who will generate any of them.

Comment: I'd like to suggest something you can try. Try a specific example. Very specific. Take the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, the integers. Let $f$ and $g$ be any two relatively prime integers; a very specific example would be $f=2$, $g=3$. Now write down elements of $(2)$ and elements of $(3)$. And figure out the intersection (elements that are in both of those). Can you see what would be a generator for the intersection?

Comment: Taking the two ideals generated by $(2)$ and $(3)$, I noticed that the intersection are multiples common of 3 and 2. Who generates the ideal $(2) \cap (3)$ is $(6)$

Comment: @JucySantos Right, $(2) \cap (3)$ is generated by $2 \cdot 3$, in other words $6$. Can you get the same result for another example, such as $(3) \cap (5)$? Can you prove the same result for relatively prime elements of a factorial domain?

Comment: Yes, who generates the ideal $(3) \cap (5)$ is the $lcm (3,5)$. Thus for two relatively prime ideals of a factorial domain the generating set will be $lcm (f, g).$

Comment: @ZachTeitler   Let's try it. For $(f) \cap (g) \subset (lcm(f,g))$ : if $h \in (f) \cap (g)$, then $h=f \cdot q$ and $h = g \cdot p$, for some $ p, q $ in a factorial domain $C$. As $h=f \cdot q$ and $h = g \cdot p$ $\Rightarrow f|h$ and $g|h$, using the definition of common multiple minimum we have $ lmc (f, g) | h $. Therefore, $ h \in lmc (f, g)$. That's what I've been able to write for this part, however, I'd like to know where I use $ f $ and $ g $ being relatively prime and how can I guarantee that it will in fact be the minimum?

Comment: Can you show that $\operatorname{lcm}(f,g)=fg$? That is because $\gcd(f,g)=1$.

Comment: For positive integers $f$ and $g$ we have:
$$gcd(f,g)lcm(f,g)=f \cdot g$$ If $gdc(f,g)=1$, then $lcm(f,g)=f \cdot g$. Right? thanks